# How to call pg_copy_from using the Yii2 framework?

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2

I have a function to work with *Postgresql*: [pg_copy_from](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-copy-from.php).

I write just as documentation says:

```
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost user=user password=123 dbname=test") or die("Could not connect");
$result = pg_copy_from($db, 'public.my_table (id, test_id,lock_name,func_type)', $data, ',');
```

Is it possible to do this operation using the Yii2 framework? Something like that:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand("pg_copy_from('public.my_table (id, test_id,lock_name,func_type)')")->execute($data);
```

Comment: Take a look at [`yii\db\Command::batchInsert()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-command#batchInsert()-detail). Maybe that's what you are looking for?

Comment: @MichalHynčica no)) I need exactly pg copy

Comment: Well, yii uses PDO internally for db connections. So, you can't directly use `pg_copy_from` but you should be able to use PDO's alternative [`pgsqlCopyFromArray()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.pgsqlcopyfromarray.php) like this: `Yii::$app->db->pdo->pgsqlCopyFromArray(...);`

Comment: @MichalHynčica understood. at the moment I use [pg_copy_from](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-copy-from.php)  is it a wrapper for pgsqlCopyFromArray ?

Comment: `Yii::$app->db->pdo` --- I didn't know that)). Thanks. Maybe that's what I need))

Comment: It's not a wrapper of `pg_copy_from`. It's from different library/driver (PDO vs. PgSQL) but it should do the same thing at database level.